# Finder item info not showing image dimensions

Tags: macos, finder

[image]

My OS X Lion usually shows file info like *image dimensions*, *file count*, *file size* or *duration* (Show View Options → Show item info).

[image]

But in one folder on one drive I do not get the image dimensions, (or music *file duration*). *Folder count* and *file size* (only of certain types like zip files apparently) still show.

If I rename the folder then the item info shows normally, but rename back and it's gone again.

If I copy a file to the root of the disk or another folder on the disk, the item info shows normally.

Is there any way to change or reset these settings?

---

edit:
i tried onyx delete all dsstore did not work

i just now tried rebuilding folder structure and it seemed like it worked if i made all new dirs instead of copying but after relaunch finder back to no info

it works if i rename it but damn there has to be a way to reset it?

Comment: The second screenshot looks so weird. Like it was stitched together. Anyway, can you open *Terminal.app* and `ls -l@ /path/to/folder`? If you completely trash the folder, move its contents away before, and then recreate the folder with the same name, does that work?

Comment: One more thing: In the terminal, try `rm /path/to/folder/.DS_Store`, relaunch the Finder by `alt`-clicking its icon in the Dock and selecting "Relaunch" and see if that works for you.

Comment: Is that on an external drive? What about the `ls` line I gave you? Can't you show me the output?

Answer (score 2):

Open your spotlight settings and click on the privacy tab.

If you folder is in there, Finder cant access your information.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or **View** -> **Show View Options** from the Finder menu) then click **Show item info**.

[image: Mac OS X Finder: View Options]